# audio processing in labVIEW( Is stream process possible ?? )

Tags: audio, signal-processing, microphone, labview, audio-processing

I am quite new to LabVIEW and NI devices.

I am working on Active Noise Cancellation Project, where I will be using two microphones input and one loud speaker as output. I have NI myRIO 1900 and CDAQ 9178 devices in our university lab. I need to do real time audio processing, I will collect data from microphone and process it using filtered XLMS algorithm to produce anti noise from loud speaker and other microphone is error microphone. I want to process data so quickly( within 1.7 msec ) so I will have real time response at 44100 sample rate !! My question is , 'is it possible to do with labview ?? and is stream processing possible in labVIEW?? and can I achieve so small audio latencies as mentioned above ??'

I have searched for audio processing objects in labview help. I can only find 'Acquire Sound', 'Play Waveform', surprisingly 'Acquire Sound configuration ' will work only for duration of minimum of 1 second not less than that !!! I can't input the time milli seconds !!!( I am still facing problem installing myRIO, so I have used host computed VI to do this.)

Please help !! Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you should be looking into is the FPGA part of the myRIO.  You’re never going to be able to get 1.7ms response time via the host computer.  The FPGA can access the Analogue inputs and outputs, so if you can get your algorithm to compile onto the FPGA then it should work.

Comment: How to find whether I can compile my Filtered xLMS Algorithm onto the FPGA, Can you provide me some source where I can find more information about FPGA capabilities and its limitations. I have searched for it, I can only find basic info on FPGA ! Thank You

Comment: Did you Google “LabVIEW FPGA” or just “FPGA”?   LabVIEW FPGA is a special extension of LabVIEW that produces FPGA code.  You would have to write your algorithm in that.

Comment: If you're new to LabVIEW and the myRIO it looks as if this would be a good place to start: http://www.ni.com/academic/students/learn-rio/

Comment: @James I did search for LabVIEW FPGA, I can only find basic info not technical info like its capabilities for signal processing / audio processing, what are functions available in FPGA for audio processing. But thanks! I will try them on my own and find

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with LabVIEW, insofar as any algorithm you want to code up can be executed by LabVIEW. If you're asking whether there is a library that already exists to do the filtering you're wanting to do, you may want to explore the NI Sound & Vibration toolkit, which is sold separate from LabVIEW, or explore third-party libraries.

The raw waveform mathematics abilities that come with LabVIEW are fairly extensive. You should be able to code whatever transforms you want if you know the base math.